# How does facebook recognize where i'm from

Tags: facebook, localization

Does anyone knows on pages like: 
https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?fref=ts 
How facebook knows where am I from and depending on that he shows post which are in language which facebook thinks it suits me. 
(Example current CocaCola he shows posts in German)
I know that when admin posts something on page like coca cola... He chooses language group and depending on that group ex.Spanish Language, post see people form Spain on Spain language.

Note: None of my account paramaters doesn't implement language which facebook shows me currenty(German), my facebook is on English, I was born and live in France, languages i speak are English and Spain.

Comment: See [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales).

Answer (score 0):

Applications can simply track your PC and hence the IP address of your PC which intern will help in identifying your current location. When you browse webpages you send a request header with this and other important local information. This is disregarding GPS and other information that you might have allowed facebook to access.